# NUnit framework requires main method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

Started learning **C#** with **Selenium** (done Selenium with Java for quite a while) and noticed that NUnit framework requires static main method to be declared. I've gone through several tutorials (video and regular web pages) and nowhere main method is declared. Any ideas how to omit the declaration of this method? I chose in VS2015 >> File >> New >> Project >>Templates >> Visual C# >> Test >> Unit Testing Project and setup Output type >> Console Application. Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, NUnit definitely doesn't require a `Main` method. Normally you'd create a class library rather than a console app, and run the tests with a test runner. The type of your project is what's requiring the Main method...

Comment: @GrantWinney I'll try to provide code example

Comment: @GrantWinney So the proper way to run tests is using NUnit.ConsoleRunner?

Comment: @GrantWinney at the nuget level there a lot of options for NUnit. I'l figure which one exactly for what you mentioned. Thank you for the help. +1